# Trouble installing R from homebrew formula (Intel Mac Pro)

Tags: r, macos, homebrew

I'm having trouble installing R from a homebrew formula on our Intel garbage can mac pro at work. I was having trouble installing tidyverse from source code so I removed and have been attempting to reinstalling R, as I thought it might have been a version mismatch somewhere.

I used

`brew install R`

and after a bunch of output where it's downloading other packages, I get back the following

```
==> Installing dependencies for r: libpng, freetype, fontconfig, gettext, libffi, pcre, glib, pkg-config, libpthread-stubs, xorgproto, libxau, libxdmcp, libxcb, libx11, libxext, libxrender, lzo, pixman, cairo, gmp, isl, mpfr, libmpc, lz4, xz, zstd, gcc, jpeg-turbo, openblas, pcre2, readline, ca-certificates, openssl@1.1 and tcl-tk
==> Installing r dependency: libpng
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
Error: Command failed with exit 129: git
```

Is this in fact a git error? What is the -C command?

Things I've tried:

- removing and reinstalling command line tools
- removing and reinstalling Homebrew

My machine:

Mac Pro (Late 2013)
2.7 GHz 12-Core Xeon E5

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: It's better to install from CRAN than the homebrew version:  that way you can use the prebuilt binaries that are on CRAN.  The ones you build on homebrew may be fine, but you can't necessarily mix CRAN and homebrew builds.

Comment: Hrmmm, I have been using the brew version on my own machine (M1 Max) and on our other MP (same config) for a while with no issues. It's just this one, where both CRAN and Brew versions of R were installed by different users. In trying to strip everything out and start again I've found what appears to be a bigger issue that is turning into a bit of a road block

Comment: I'm not saying Homebrew doesn't work, I'm saying you should avoid mixing it with CRAN builds. I avoid Homebrew completely, because you get more knowledgeable help from people who build the CRAN versions.  The R Core group doesn't support Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I think it tries to use an old version of `git` at `/usr/bin/git`, but you need to run `brew install git` to install a newer version of `git` to `/usr/local/bin/git`.

If `/usr/local/bin/` isn't on your `PATH` before `/usr/bin/`, then you can add a line like this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However `/usr/local/bin` is included in `/etc/paths` by default, so it should be added to `PATH` by programs that run `path_helper` (like Terminal and iTerm 2 but not Script Editor or Emacs.app).

Comment: Appears that I have ```git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)```.

In an ironic twist, after I run ```brew install git``` I get the same ```Unknown option: -C```